# edit my interesting tags

Tags: support, tags

I am not as interested as I once was in some topics. How can I remove them from my interesting tag list? Adding them to ignored tags may work, but I want less clutter, don't want my tag lists to grow indefinately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go anywhere -- just click the little [x] next to the tag on the sidebar.

Comment: It seems that the [x]'s are appearing at the last moment of loading the page. Therefor I didn't see them there at first.

Comment: I had no idea that those X's were functional! I thought they were just separators for a list of tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Click on your username and go to the tab "prefs". There you will see small crosses next to the tags to delete them.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/USERID?tab=preferences#sort-top